# Android studio text in next line

Tags: android

I am working on android studio. I have a layout

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/operator_info_table"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="1">

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:text="Qty"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:text="Price"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/survey_detail_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:focusable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

In the `recycler view` I have added a table

```
for (Product product :
                    productArrayList) {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
                TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                layoutParams.setMargins(10,0,0,0);
                TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams3 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                tr.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                TextView t1 = new TextView(getActivity());
                t1.setSingleLine(false);
                t1.setMaxLines(2);
                t1.setText(product.getProductName());
                t1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                tr.addView(t1);

                TextView t2 = new TextView(getActivity());
                t2.setText(product.getQty());
                layoutParams2.setMargins(70,0,0,0);
                t2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
                tr.addView(t2);

                TextView t3 = new TextView(getActivity());
                t3.setText(product.getBookingPrice());
                layoutParams3.setMargins(70,0,0,0);
                t3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams3);

                tr.addView(t3);
                operatorInfoTable.addView(tr);
            }
```

**Output**

[image]

I the name to be in the next line if it's long enough. Just like in the above image `ACEFYL COUGH SYP 125 ML` is on a single line. But the part `... SYP 125 ML` should be on the next line. I have already tried with `t1.setSingleLine(false); t1.setMaxLines(2);` but it doesn't helped me out.

**Update 1**

After following the @kai solution. I am getting below result

[image]

The `Quantity` and the `Price` is not aligned with the heads.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you define "long enough"? Do you want to distribute columns evenly?

Comment: @Kai yes i want the columns distribution evenly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could distribute the columns evenly by setting weight attribute(1 : 1 : 1).

**xml:**

> android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/operator_info_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Name"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Qty"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**programmatically:**

```
TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
```

### update:

You need to align text in textview with the same gravity attribute in xml.

setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) programmatically if you set `android:gravity="center".

```
    t1.setGravity(Gravity.START)
    t2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
    t3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
```

The value of gravity depends on the UI you want.

Comment: by applying your code the text is evenly wrapped but the TextView is not

Comment: Maybe it's because you set margins of the textviews.

Comment: I tried to remove but still same result

Comment: Do you have more details about the result? I don't fully understand what you mean "text is evenly wrapped but the TextView is not".

Comment: let me share with you

Comment: kindly see my `Update 1`

Comment: It seems that you need to set Gravity of the textview.

Comment: You should set Gravity of t1, t2 and t3 if you want to align the text in textview to "Name", "Qty" and "Price".

Comment: ok to what value of gravity ?

Comment: As same as the gravity of the heads. See my update.